# Unexpected sscanf Result

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

I have a `sscanf` statement that is behaving unexpectedly. This is somewhere around loop #8000 that it suddenly does this. This is the code, where `str` is a string parsed from a file:

```cpp
char a1[6], a2[6], op[6], a3[6];
int success = sscanf(str.c_str(),"%*s %s %*s %s %s %s",a1, a2, op, a3);
```

And this is the gdb output on the problem line (`str` is `"assign po012 = po011;"`):

```
(gdb) print str
$9 = {<std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>> = {<No data fields>}, static __short_mask = 1, static __long_mask = 1,
  __r_ = {<std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__rep, 0, false>> = {__value_ = {{__l = {__cap_ = 97, __size_ = 23, __data_ = 0x1003001d0 "  assign po012 = po011;"}, __s = {{
              __size_ = 97 'a', __lx = 97 'a'},
            __data_ = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\027\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\320\001\060\000\001\000\000"}, __r = {__words = {
              97, 23,
              4298113488}}}}}, <std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::allocator<char>, 1, true>> = {<std::__1::allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, static npos = 18446744073709551615}
(gdb) n
81                  string A1(a1);
(gdb) print a1
$10 = "\000o012"
(gdb) print a2
$13 = "po011;"
```

`a2` has the expected value, but what is happening to `a1` in just this one case?

Comment: why it has a `'\0'` instead of `'p`'? no idea, but try setting a watchpoint on `a1[0]`

Comment: `sscanf` is a `C` API not `C++`.

Comment: Everything works as it should and as it is documented: https://godbolt.org/z/offP9K

Comment: The `str` value shown does not match the `sscanf` pattern being searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays have length six:

```
char a1[6], a2[6], op[6], a3[6];
```

Yet, `sscanf` causes `"po011;"` to be written in `a2`, and this requires **seven** characters, since `sscanf` will add the null terminator. Hence, `sscanf` causes undefined behavior.

Pragmatically, in your implementation the null terminator was added to the beginning of `a1`, which changed from the intended `"po012"` to `"\000o012"` (the initial `p` was overwritten). It looks like your implementation chose to store `a1` right after `a2`, so overflowing `a2` overwrote `a1`. This is one of the things that can happen when undefined behavior is triggered.

Comment: I did increase the char array length to 8, with no effect. The original run was on my mac, but when I cloned on a RHEL machine it worked. Do you know why this changed it?

Comment: increasing the array length to 10 fixed it on the mac, I think the mechanism you described is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @CaitlinSlicker I can not clearly understand what's going on in your code. Maybe in your file there's a longer field? Changing OS / compiler could also make undefined behavior incidentally "work" as expected, but this should not be relied upon since it can stop working at any moment. Check that in the file the fields are long enough. You could also use a format specifier with string size like `%9s` to prevent the buffer overflow. Also, in C++ you could avoid scanf and work with std::string instead.